# Difference between method and property on an object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, methods, prototype, ecmascript-5

I am trying to understand how properties of an object relate to methods defined on the object's prototype. The following code prints 'ECMA style 5', while I would expect it to print 'ECMA style 3'.

```
var util = require('util');

function MyError() { }
util.inherits(MyError, Error);

Object.defineProperty(MyError.prototype, 'toJSON', {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function () {
    return 'ECMA5 style';
  }
});

MyError.prototype.toJSON = function() {
  return 'ECMA3 style';
}

var x = new MyError();
console.log(JSON.stringify(x));
```

I am reading through an article [1](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/es5-chapter-1-properties-and-property-descriptors/), but I cannot grok why style 3 is not printed since it is defined second in the file. Shouldn't this override the existing method definition?

I am running node v0.10.21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with whether you're in a Node environment or not. If a specific attribute of the property is not set, they default to `false`. Data properties have the following attributes (description in parentheses is for when the attribute is false):

- `configurable` (cannot be deleted, nor can attributes or type of property be changed)
- `enumerable` (cannot be seen in a for-in loop)
- `writable` (read-only but can still be deleted)
- `value` (the value itself)

Because you haven't specified in your call to `Object.defineProperty` that `writable` is `true`, it cannot be written to and therefore is read-only ([reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.1)).

By default, "standard" properties have all of these attributes (apart from `value`) explicitly set as `true` (internally), which is why it works normally. A good note by [Mike Edwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966019/difference-between-method-and-property-on-an-object-in-node-js/19966108#comment29721184_19966108) is that attempting to do what you were doing in ES5 strict mode will throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: True.. probably hook this up... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description

Comment: @conorgil If you run your script in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) you'll see that the `ECMA3` assignment actually throws an error.

Comment: I ran it in strict mode and it did indeed error. When I added writeable:true to the call in Object.defineProperty, then it worked as I initially expected.